# Installing jar file to Tomcat web application

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, jar

How do I install a 3rd party JAR file to my tomcat web application?

I have placed it in every folder I can think of, and am referencing it like:

```
import com.google.api.translate;
```

Is there a particular folder? I have tried WEB_INF/lib

Comment: WEB_INF/lib is the correct place. What error messages are you getting?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you are NOT importing the classes like that.  That looks like a package name, and if it is you would get Java compilation errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all apps on Tomcat need that JAR, the place to put it would be /lib if you're using Tomcat 6.x or higher and /server/lib if it's version 5.x or lower.

If only your app needs a 3rd party JAR, put it in WEB-INF/lib.

I hope you're packaging your app as a WAR file.

> I have placed it in every folder I can think of

I'd recommend reading a bit more about Tomcat and CLASSPATH before you proceed.

```
import com.google.api.translate;
```

This doesn't look like proper Java to me.  Shouldn't that be:

```
import com.google.api.translate.*;
```

What is the name of the JAR containing those classes?  Where did you find it?

Looks like you want to use Google's translate API somehow.

Comment: Do I not need to add it to my ant build xml files etc?

Comment: If you're using Ant to compile and package your app, you need to make sure that the JAR is in the Ant CLASSPATH and gets copied into your WAR file's WEB-INF/lib.

Comment: It's in the ant classpath, but no go :( Must be making an error somewhere.

Comment: I asked findjar.com to find a JAR with that class in it, but no go.

Comment: Looks like the google-api-translate-java-0.92.jar at http://code.google.com/p/google-api-translate-java/

Comment: Turns out I needed to reference it in my ant build.xml.